Scheduled triggered flow is not working for after activation but it is working as expected under flow debugger
I have created a scheduled trigger flow to update contact record after meeting few criteria. When I give contact record Id which matches the criteria from flow debugger then it is updating the record however when I set the timings to match system time zone with 5 min later and activate the flow the record is not updating. please let me know what I might be missing.
I tried to set up debug logs with AUtomated user but didn't receive any trace logs and also The flow is listed under scheduled jobs with the time which I added.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
